Does PyDev support python async?
The application I am attempting to run under Eclipse/PyDev uses the python async keyword and the asyncio package. Does PyDev support asyncio? I imagine this would affect how stack histories are displayed and perhaps other things.

Yes, PyDev does support asyncio.
You shouldn't really have to do anything special (besides configuring a Python interpreter that also supports the asyncio keyword).
